# Parameterized query and NULL DateTime value

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm working a program that is pulling a string field from an access database, separating out a name (first and last) from a date then save the name separately from the date in a different access database.

I've got everything done except some of the date values are null so I need to parametrize the SQL but I haven't been able to figure out how to do make the parametrization work.

I've put in dummy values for the variable and it adds them to the table just fine. I've cut out the other variables in the code snippet below since they're all repeats of what's there. os is a list holding data from a structure.

```
string sqlcmd = "INSERT INTO signatures VALUES ('" + os.QASignature + "', 'QADate = @QADATE'";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand SQLCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, Connection);
using (SQLCommand)
{
    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@QADATE", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = os.QADate;
    SQLDataReader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following should be what you want:

```
string sqlcmd = "INSERT INTO signatures (QASignature, QADate) VALUES (?, ?)";
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand SQLCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, Connection))
{
    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter() { Name = "QASignature", Value = os.QASignature, DbType = DbType.String});
    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter() { Name = "QADATE", Value = os.QADate, DbType = DbType.DateTime});
    SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Use ExecuteReader or ExecuteScalar when you want to return something
}
```

If os.QADate is nullable (`DateTime?` or `System.Nullable<DateTime>`), then you would do the following:

```
if(os.QADate == null) //Could easily be os.QADate == DateTime.MinValue too, for example
{
    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter() { Name = "@QADATE", Value = DBNull.Value, DbType = DbType.DateTime});
}
else{
    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter() { Name = "@QADATE", Value = os.QADate, DbType = DbType.DateTime});
}
```

Note that you shouldn't mix string concatenation and parameters like in your original example - it's one or the other! And really, it should be *just* parameterization to guard against SQL Injection, and to gain other benefits (like easier typing and, in some RDBMS, parameterized queries perform better).

Also note that OleDBCommand does not benefit from named parameters - parameters must be added to the query in the order they appear in the SQL. This is why the SQL Query contains two question marks - they are simply placeholders.

Comment: After I put that into my program I get the following errors:
"The name 'Value' does nt exist in the current context"
"'System.Data.DbType' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'".

Comment: Nevermind, It needed to be like "SQLCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(Name = "QASignature", DbType.String).Value = os.QASignature)" rather than what you had.

Answer (score 4):

You need to "convert" `null` to [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx). One way to achieve that, assuming QADate is a nullable DateTime (so DateTime?) might  be:

```
... .Value = os.QADate ?? DBNull.Value;
```

?? being the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Edit: You might actually need to cast to make sure both operands are of the same type:

```
... .Value = (object)os.QADate ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Also, why don't you use a parameter for QASignature?? Why are you "inlining" that value? I don't know what QASignature would contain, but this leaves you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

And finally, why are you using [ExecuteReader()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader.aspx) for an insert? Why not use [ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

DateTime cannot be null, if the value is not initialized it is DateTime.MinValue.
You need to test for this case and use the parameters also for the string values.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
....

string sqlcmd = "INSERT INTO signatures VALUES (@QASignature, @QADATE)"; 
using(OleDbCommand SQLCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, Connection))
{ 
    SQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QASignature",  os.QASignature);
    SQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@QADATE", OleDbType.Date).Value = 
               (os.QADate == DateTime.MinValue 
               ? (object)DBNull.Value
               : (object)os.QADate); 
    SQLDataReader = SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

By the way, an insert statement usually is executed by `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: `DateTime` cannot be null indeed, `DateTime?` however, can :-) I am assuming the latter since user1533116 states: 'some of the date values are null'.

Comment: Sorry, @Steve, I accidentally edited your post. Have rolled back to original version. I removed the System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand section so didn't change the nature of it. I must be going blind.

Comment: @dash, OK, however your edit was right. Let me restore your changes :-)

Comment: The only other comment I had was that you can't set the value that way because there is no conversion between DBNull.Value and a DateTime - you can't use the ternary [conditional] operator this way unfortunately. However, it's still a +1 in that you are the only person to mention DateTime.MinValue in context.

Comment: @dash, right I haven't noticed that. However adding a cast to object works. Definitively your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx):

```
SQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@QADATE", 
                          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

As a side note, using [OleDbParameterCollection.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) automatically infers the data type and allows you to shorten your code:

```
SQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QADATE", DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Nullable(of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) structure. Then you can set it only if there is actually a variable in your source object. Otherwise the value is set to Null and passes itself nicely into SQL Parameters. A lot of the old TableAdapter classes and newer EntityFramework objects work with the Nullable (of T) structure as well.